# On How To Switch CChildView Objects That Represents The View

Tags: c++, mfc

I have CMainFrame class for my main window, and CChildView class for my view as generated by AppWizard. I have created two CChildView objects to represent two different view (client area Panels for controls) using m_wndView1.Create() and m_wndView2.Create(). but the ID used in the Create() function seem to be a problem. If its not AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST the view does not display. Please I need a pointer to learn about the ID and how to solve the problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create the first view with `AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST`, the next one with `AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST+1`. The one with `AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST` will be active.

It is unclear what you mean by:

> I have created two CChildView objects to represent two different view

It seams that you are trying to use the same CchildView for different views. I recommend that you create different classes for different views, e.g. CChildView1 and CChildView2. If you want to have two views attached to the same document, you need to use [CDocument::AddView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e59dtf8h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). In the link for this method you will find how to use AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST to switch the views

Comment: Thanks for your time. this may make it clearer. I want to use different objects of the CChildView to create many views which i can switch at runtime, and my App is not a Document/View App. See code below: <code>// MainFrm.cpp int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct) { if (CFrameWnd::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1) return -1; m_wndView1.Create(NULL, NULL, AFX_WS_DEFAULT_VIEW, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST, NULL);m_wndView2.Create(NULL, NULL, AFX_WS_DEFAULT_VIEW, CRect(0, 0, 0, 0), this, AFX_IDW_PANE_FIRST+1, NULL);</code>